# Is “Das leben ist schön wenn du es nicht zu leben hast” an idiom?

Tags: idiom

A pair of graves in a local cemetery. He is a World War II Navy veteran who died in 1996. His wife died in 2006. I don’t think the surname is German (Mack), and neither is her given name. I wouldn’t expect a *Navy* sailor to have a war bride. There is no obvious German connection, yet she has the following on her grave marker:

> Das leben ist schön wenn du es nicht zu leben hast

Google translates this as

> Life is beautiful when you do not have to live.

and gives a possible alternate translation of

> That’s nice life if you did not live.

I was wondering if this is a German idiom with a meaning beyond the literal words.

1/19/2016  Thank you all for your help. I think that "Life is beautiful if you don’t have to live it." is a good answer, and agree with the general thought that she must have had a hard life, particularly the 10 years between his passing and hers. When I see a wide gap like that, I think how terrible the loneliness and the longing must have been.  Thank you again.

Comment: "Mack" *could* be a German name, or indicate a German heritage - at least I wouldn't consider it as an unusual name in Germany. The first translation seems more fitting, although I'd rather translate it as "Life is beautiful when you do not have to live **it**" - ("life" being used here an object, as in "to live your life"). I haven't heard this before, even less as a ("common") idiom, but maybe someone can give a real answer about that.

Comment: What *is* her given name? :)  And I'm with @Marco13 on that one: I've never heard it before; I wouldn't consider it idiomatic phrase, it might be a lesser known aphorism, though.

Comment: "Mack" actually *is* a pretty common German name (and common in other languages as well). And there were definitely many other ways for an  woman (allegededly of German background) of getting married to a US citicen than being a war bride. The inscription isn't any idiom I'd know nor a well-known aphorism in German.

Comment: One could speculate about the deeper meaning of this statement, though. I could imagine that it suggests that the life of a person may look "nice" for others, but that there are possibly hidden burdens, troubles or challenges that make life particularly difficult for the person herself. But again, that's just a guess.

Comment: In the online telephone book of Munich, there are [eighty entries for *Mack*](http://www.dastelefonbuch.de/Suche/Mack/M%C3%BCnchen). (For Germany in total, the threshold of 1000 is reached.)

Comment: It's very imaginable that this person, who speaks German as her native language, came up with this phrase on her own. Mack can apparently be a German name.

Answer (score 5):

The phrase in itself is not an idiom: there is no deeper hidden meaning besides the actual (literal?) translation of the words. I won’t say I’ve never heard it before because it’s an idiomatic sentence and entirely possible that I *did* read or hear it at some point, but it is not one quoted or stated heavily that any German would instantly recognise. (While I can’t speak for Switzerland and Austria, I don’t think that it would be an idiom there.)

The Google translation is a tad off. A better translation would be:

> Life is beautiful if you don’t have to live it.

If I had to do some interpretation, I would assume that she had to overcome numerous hardships in life but still tried to make the most out of it. That is just a wild guess, though; I don’t know the people in question.

Finally, while I don’t know anybody having the surname *Mack* I wouldn’t find it unusual for a German name.

Comment: The Yandex translation of the phrase in question is  "Life is beautiful when you don't have it to live."  Repositioning the word "it" changes your phrase to a positive expression about Life.

Comment: @К.КеллоггСмиф The thing is that the original German is not exactly positive …